How to boost Bass of a 2.1 Class D Amplifier based Karaoke Mixer System
I have created my own Class D amplifier based 2.1 Karaoke Music System using ready to connect modules according to the following diagram to create the music system.

I have used probably three very common modules which many of you may already be familiar with. I am still linking sample Amazon links for these 3 modules, so that it becomes clear.

Module 1 - FM/BT/Module with display and remote: https://www.amazon.com/BOOMBOOST-Bluetooth-Player-Decoder-Receiver/dp/B08H15KMFM
Module 2 - IOTAudios PT2399 Microphone Amplifier and Reverberation Module: https://www.amazon.com/XH-M173-Microphone-Amplifier-Karaoke-Reverberation/dp/B09GC9MRLJ
Module 3 - 2.1 Channel TPA3116 Class D Amplifier Module with BT Audio 50W+50W+100W: https://www.amazon.com/Amplifier-TPA3116D2-Subwoofer-Voltage-Equipment/dp/B08XKJVJGY

TPA3116 Class D Amplifier has a push button cum VC to adjust volume and switch between the built-in BT Audio or AUX IN.
Problem:
When I play music using the TPA3116 Class D Amplifier module's built-in BT Audio, the audio quality is fantastic with very satisfying bass from the subwoofer. But when I switch to AUX IN, it effectively plays the audio from the FM/BT/AUX player via the PT2399 Module mixed with the Microphone inputs and the audio quality drops. I seem to hear an audio with very low bass and high treble.
Question:
I know how to use a high pass filter/ subwoofer amplifier standalonely to drive a Subwoofer for high bass. I can also build a simplified high pass filter with a Capacitor and a Resistor. But I don't know where it fits in the circuit to make sure the audio from the PT2399 board only gets the boost and not the built-in BT Audio of the Class D Amplifier module. I am not sure low pass filter is applicable at the output of which one among the first two modules. So, can someone please help me figure out if I can put a cap + resistor based high pass filter in each of the left and right audio inputs between Module 1 and Module 2 OR between Module 2 and Module 3 to get the bass boost I'm looking for? Is there any simple hack I can do within the PT2399 module to boost the bass of the output without sacrificing the gain?

Have you tried connecting the BT module directly to the amplifier board module (TPA3116) without PT2399 module to see if the problem is still there?

I tried this, this doesn't sound correct either. The bass is very low if I directly connect the MP3 Player directly to the amplifier as well. So, seems the problem is with the origin of the music tracks from the MP3/BT module only. Any solution for this?

Without seeing the full schematic, it is hard to pinpoint the issue, but I saw a schematic of an amplifier board with the same IC but without BT or anything else, and it has two stereo amplifiers built-in: one for the two stereo channels, and one for the subwoofer (it is using both channels as one to give it more output power, and it has a separate SUB(woofer) input which would come from the sum of the two channels combined and run through a low-pass filter. It is possible your board does that for its own BT audio, but not for the AUX IN.

I have checked the pictures of this board more carefully and found more info about it. My guess is that the AUX IN goes through the BT chip first, and that the sound may be distorted going through it, but sounds OK if it comes from the BT internal circuitry itself. Also, I suppose you know what all the potentiometers do, adjusting both bass and treble volume AND low-pass and high-pass frequency points. There is also a small switch between the pots which either cuts low frequencies off or it lets all frequencies go through. If those are not the issue, then it is likely the first thing I said.

@EdinFifić I tried adjusting the POTs and changing the switch, nothing gave me the dept I am hearing for the same song played from Youtube on my mobile. My guess is, if the problem is of the amplifier board then your first guess is true. Perhaps it uses two separate high pass filter circuitry one for it's own BT Audio and one for the AUX IN and the first one filters better.

Exactly! If there were a schematic of your board, it would make our job of figuring the problem out much easier. Is there a marking on your BT chip, or is it erased? Can you tell us what it is, if it's still there? I can see Left and Right channel traces going from the BT chip to the pots, and the AUX IN going to the chip. WHAT I ALSO SUSPECT is that they may have placed low value capacitors between AUX IN and BT chip, so the bass is reduced. It wouldn't be the first nor the only time the cheap no-brand makers do that.

Signals from vocal microphones must be connected to a sound system which do not have especially deep bass response in those mic channels, because it's very easy to blow into the mic and the generated bass noise would easily make the sub-bass speaker to hit the ground. Even the deepest bass singer wouldn't produce anything as heavy in subbass range by singing.
I guess the recorded music connected via the mic preamp board gets the same bass reduction as the mic signals. That could be called a major design specification failure if the recorded music cannot be fed without the harmful bass cut. Check if there's a jumper or switch for that option.
Fixing: Use a mixer between the mic preamp board and the power amp board. Inject the recorded music to that mixer. It can be a passive resistor network (total 4 resistors) if there's enough gain reserve in the power amp board. If that gain reserve doesn't exist the mixer must be constructed so that it doesn't attenuate (=2 input summing amplifier; one for Left and one for Right channel)
The next image shows the passive 4 resistor mixer:

If the reason of the problem isn't bass cutting in the mic preamp board, but your source of recorded music doesn't produce enough bass, this is, of course, useless. In that case you can try to insert a bass booster to the output of the recorded music source. I would try the  bass-treble tone adjusting circuit which is common in hifi and music instrument amplifiers. It helps if the wanted bass is only attenuated, but it's still there. It doesn't help if the wanted bass is filtered totally out in the recorded music source.
Do web search for "tone control circuit" and you find numerous schematics. Passive versions reduce volume, but that's no harm if you have enough gain reserve. If not, use a version which has an amplifier.
NOTE: This all is only guessing and recalling some general elementaries. Hopefully someone writes something based on actual experiments with the same boards. Better to start also your own tests immediately.

Thanks @Absus4 for responding. I'll try both as suggested. But can you please elaborate a little more about the passive resistor network you mentioned about?

@sribasu It's added to the answer.
